# Colors on objects, but not my images(movie background)

Tags: rendering, color

Ive made my animation. I followed a few steps on how to make shadows on to a plane that only shows shadows in my final render. After that I was messing around with my compositing to make my scene look like it should, i rendered and.... I get color objects, no color on my transperent background.
Can you help me with help from this screenshot?
[image]

Comment: You can upload your .blend file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ Then edit your question and paste in the link.

Comment: don't use a math node to multiply. Use a color mix node instead and set that one to multiply mode.